# Letters in JTextPane are colored after delay

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, jtextpane

I have simple text editor which colours JAVA key words blue. This is the code:

```
class MainPanel extends JPanel {

    private int WIDTH = 800;
    private int HEIGHT = 500;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextPane codePane = new JTextPane();
    private StyledDocument doc = codePane.getStyledDocument();

    MainPanel(JFrame frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(codePane);
        add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        codePane.addKeyListener(new MainPanel.KeyHandler());
        codePane.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        //Loading key words..
        //...
    }

    private class KeyHandler extends KeyAdapter {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ev) {
            String code = codePane.getText();
            SimpleAttributeSet set = new SimpleAttributeSet();
            StyleConstants.setForeground(set, Color.BLACK);
            doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, code.length(), set, true);
            //Change keywords color
            int lastIndex = 0;
            for (int a = 0; a < words.length; a++) {
                set = new SimpleAttributeSet();
                if (Arrays.asList(keywords).contains(words[a])) {
                    StyleConstants.setForeground(set, Color.BLUE);
                }
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(lastIndex, words[a].length(), set, true);
                lastIndex += words[a].length() + 1; //+1 bo jeszcze spacja po słowie
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that text highlighting (in keyTyped event) takes place before placing letter in text area. So when I type in: "int" it wont colour it blue but when I type one more character "int" will be coloured blue eg. "intR", "int" will be coloured blue and R letter will be black. How to prevent it? One solution is to replace keyTyped with keyReleased but I cant do it because I’m planning to do some things while <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and <kbd>TAB</kbd> are pressed and I need to use consume method on them which doesn’t work on keyReleased.

Answer (score 2):

> One solution is to replace keyTyped with keyReleased

Don't use a KeyListener. You should be using a DocumentListener. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a Document Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more information.

> Im planning to do some things while ENTER and TAB

You should be using Key Bindings. Look at the Table of Contents from the above link and you will find a section on `How to Use Key Bindings`.

Answer (score 0):

hi i this how you echo the string from a Jtextfield

```
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class FrmPrueba extends JFrame {

    public FrmPrueba() {
        setTitle("Prueba de pintado");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 300);
        setLookAndFeel();
        JTextField jTextField = new JTextField();
        add(jTextField);
        jTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.print(e.getKeyChar());
            }
        });

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);


    }

    private void setLookAndFeel() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel());
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FrmPrueba frmPrueba = new FrmPrueba();
        frmPrueba.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```